# Java writing file on Linux which gets deleted but i can still write to it

Tags: java, linux, performance

I have a Java application which is writing files to disk.  The issue is, Linux does not lock files as Windows does, so someone can delete the file as it is being written to.  When this happens, my Java application keeps chugging along like the file still exists...even allows more writes, with no Exceptions.

I added a check for: file.exists(), however this kills my performance by almost 50%.  Anyone have any clever ideas as to how i can work around this and keep my performance high?

Comment: We had the same issue in our product - we ended up documenting that as a limitation.

Comment: You could use group permissions and lock the directory. Your program could be the only user in a group with the appropriate permissions. It's a kludge but it may help reduce surprise deletions.

Comment: Permissions won't help. After all, root (for instance) has all the power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "file" under unix is an unnamed i-node (which contains data) and a zero+ entries in directories pointing to that i-node. Zero or more. Which means you can delete the name, but the i-node will still exist, and if open, one can write into it and read from it.

But you don't need to check f.exists() at every write. Do it once in a while (let's say once in 15 seconds). Your performance won't hurt much.

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option as we can not miss anything.  I think the only solution is to use file permissions as a stop gap.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Permissions are not going to help you. Root or group member will delete your file just fine.

Comment: yes, i understand, but the performance hit is too large to check if the file exists before every write.  Just going to have to cross fingers and hope there are no accidental deletes.

Comment: you may consider to buffer records into memory, check exists() every e.g. 100 records, and then flush the records.

Comment: why the concern of what root can do?  root can do anything.  root can kill your process and deleta the files.  if you have someone with root access deleting files w/o reason, you have IT management problems that go beyond your app.  Using file permissions is the proper way to go so regular users are preventing from causing problems.  Note group member only can delete a file if you have group write permissions set.

Answer (score 7):

It's funny to hear of this being considered a "problem" -- those of us who cut their teeth on UNIX think Windows approach to file locking is crude and painful.

If you can't use file permissions to (mostly) prevent this, I think File.exists() is the only solution here, but presumably you could call it less frequently if it's causing a performance problem -- maybe from a "reaper" thread that wakes up occasionally to check for this condition.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I do not consider it a problem that the file is not "locked", i just think it is a problem that Java does not error.  I wonder how you can write to a non existent file.  Doesn't the OS toss the file handle on deleted files?

Comment: Note that this isn't a Java thing at all -- all code will do the same thing. As far as how it works: the kernel data structure for a file doesn't go away as long as any process is referencing it. UNIX is built around the notion that everything is a file -- the terminal, the network, all kinds of devices, even "/dev/null", the special file that goes nowhere -- so the notion of writing to a file that doesn't physically exist is not foreign.

Comment: File still exists, only its name is gone. Learn Unix bro! ;)

Comment: +1 - and to add, if you have this problem ... you're doing something wrong *outside* of your code. If it's just a matter of being afraid that "anyone" can come along and delete the file, as mentioned you need to use file permissions (and ownership) to prevent that. If it's that some other process is deleting them ... don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind reducing your programs portability you could use something like [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) to be notified when the file is deleted.

This functionality will, I believe, be part of JDK 7, which means you can later remove the dependance on jnotify later on.

Comment: Oy, they named it jnotify?  I suppose there is going to be pnotify, knotify, qnotify, etc., now?

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing the file with a temporary name and after write is complete you rename/move the file to it's final name/location.